# Getting a specific process id from a powershell output

Tags: powershell

Hi I'm new to powershell scripting and I would like to retrieve a specific process id based on the file's hash. However I can only get either a table with the hash value or a table with the id,process name and path

```
$ps = Get-Process | Select-Object -Property Id,ProcessName,Path

$hashlist = Get-FileHash(Get-Process|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path) -Algorithm MD5
```

Is it possible for me to merge the two tables together so that I can get a view of Id,ProcessName and Hash using the path to link them together?

Comment: Not all processes do return a path and several processes might use the same path, so I'd build a hash table with the path as key and the hash as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: totally different approach due to new information from comment**

I don't think it is so easy to identify malware with a file MD5 hash. 
Modern AntiVirusSoftware uses heuristics to overcome the problem of `mean` malware which includes random data and also obfuscates it's origin.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\11\SO_53247430.ps1

# random hex string replace with your malware signature
$MalwareMD5Hash = 'D52C11B7E076FCE593288439ABA0F6D4' 

Get-Process | Where-Object Path | Select-Object ID,Path | Group-Object Path | ForEach-Object {
   if ($MalwareMD5Hash -eq (Get-FileHash $_.Name -Alg MD5).Hash){ 
       ##iterate group to kill all processes matching
       ForEach ($PID in $_.Group.ID){
         Stop-Process -ID $PID -Force -WhatIF
       }
   }
   $_.Name | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf # to delete the physical file.
}
```

---

As I suggested in my comment:

```
$HashList = [ordered]@{}
Get-Process |Where-Object Path | Select-Object Path |Sort-Object Path -Unique | ForEach-Object {
  $HashList[$_.Path]=(Get-FileHash $_.Path -Alg MD5).Hash
  ## or the reverse, the hash as key and the path as value
  # $HashList[(Get-FileHash $_.Path -Alg MD5).Hash]=$_.Path
}
$Hashlist | Format-List
```

Shorted sample output

```
Name  : C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
Value : BFE829AB5A4B729EE4565700FC8853DA

Name  : C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
Value : E4A81EDDFF8B844D85C8B45354E4144E

Name  : C:\WINDOWS\system32\conhost.exe
Value : EA777DEEA782E8B4D7C7C33BBF8A4496

Name  : C:\WINDOWS\system32\DllHost.exe
Value : 2528137C6745C4EADD87817A1909677E
```

---

```
> $hashlist['C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE']
E4A81EDDFF8B844D85C8B45354E4144E
```

Or with the reversed list

```
> $hashlist['E4A81EDDFF8B844D85C8B45354E4144E']
C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
```

Comment: Hi, but I would like to be able to associate the hash to it's process id as well. I tried searching if there were any functions that could find the process ID using the file path but can only find methods to find the path based on ID.

Comment: It's unclear to me if you've got the md5 hash from a different source to compare with. It isn't neccessary to merge two tables when you add another property by calculating it via a Select-Object. To get process IDs matching a file path a simple `Get-Process | Where-Object Path -eq 'C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE'` for example should do.

Comment: Sorry! I should have briefly described what I'm trying to do. For my project, I have a md5 signature of a malware that renames itself randomly. Thus i need to check the running process for any process that matches the same signature and kill the process. Thus the need to be able to match the md5 of a running process to a process id in order to identify the malware.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! Turns out I was doing it a roundabout way trying to extract information from one output to compare with another. Still not very used to manipulating data in powershell. I'm trying to kill a known malware within a system hence using the md5 signature to trace it.

Comment: Added deletion of the file, remove the `-WhatIf` if the output is OK. If an answer solves your question or you find it helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: Copying this to my snipet collection `$work` has decided to implement a whitelisting application for security ... I assume this will come in handy soon. Thanks!